# How to call and launch EXE from linux \unix side?

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, unix, psexec

I have a build process that runs on Linux and UNIX hosts. It's script -based, and at the end of the process I'd like to run an **EXE** file (that can run on Windows only... yes I know it's quite weird but this is the requirement I got).
This EXE should be ran on a specific Windows machine.

My question is: Is there any utility or a technique that can send a command-line from the Linux side to the Windows side and launch it locally on the Windows side?

It may sound like psexec. I know it can run from Windows to Linux, but do you know a similar utility that supports the opposite way?

Thx

Comment: A possible solution (or duplicate) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036300/executing-exe-or-bat-file-on-remote-windows-machine-from-nix

Answer (score 4):

I have personally not tried it, but have you heard of Winexe?

> Winexe remotely executes commands on Windows NT/2000/XP/2003 systems
>   from GNU/Linux (and possibly also from other Unices capable of
>   building the Samba 4 software package).

Examples from http://micksmix.wordpress.com/2012/08/09/winexe-a-psexec-like-client-for-accessing-windows-from-linux/

> winexe --user Administrator --password=P@ssw0rd //192.168.100.105 cmd.exe

Hope this helps